# Visual basic 2012 IgnoreCase on if textbox.text = ""

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ignore-case

How do I ignore upper/lower case letters this is my code :

```
if COMMAND_TEXT.Text = "command" then
    CONSOLE.AppendText("command entered!" & Environment.NewLine)
else
     CONSOLE.AppendText("Invalid command" & Environment.NewLine)
end if
```

I am making a simple console but when I try to enter : Command 
it doesn't find anything but when I enter : command it just executes the code I want.

Do I have to make every possible text?? Like this :

```
if COMMAND_TEXT.Text = "command" then
    CONSOLE.AppendText("command entered!" & Environment.NewLine)
elseif COMMAND_TEXT.Text = "Command" then
    CONSOLE.AppendText("command entered!" & Environment.NewLine)
elseif COMMAND_TEXT.Text = "COMMAND" then
    CONSOLE.AppendText("command entered!" & Environment.NewLine)
else
     CONSOLE.AppendText("Invalid command" & Environment.NewLine)
end if
```

Or is there an other easier way like in Java EqualsIgnoreCase

Comment: Fittingly, your VB code shows a blatant disregard for conventions of upper- and lowercase spelling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would *not* recommend upper-casing or lower-casing as others have suggested. That can cause issues in some cultures, particularly Turkish. Instead, use [`String.Equals(String, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx):

```
If COMMAND_TEXT.Text.Equals("command", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

You may want to use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` or `OrdinalIgnoreCase` - it depends on the context.

I'd also strongly advise you to avoid shouty names like `COMMAND_TEXT` and use more conventional names instead.

Comment: +1 its interesting how .ToUpper() causes issues in Turkish locale.

Comment: Thanks it works great!
But how do I do that with this :
    If InStr(COMMAND_TEXT.Text, "start") Then
     ''My code
 end if

Comment: @Nobleleader13245: I suspect you want `String.IndexOf(String, StringComparison)`